# What is the conduction angle on the following?

Tags: diodes

i have found the problem and i am confused with the solution provided.
As far as i know conduction angle is given by the equation

```
ϕ=π−(2θ)
where ϕ is conduction angle, θ is where conduction starts.
```

The question and circuit diagram is shown in image.
Using the above equation the conduction angle is just 60, but here in the solution it said 120. Is it wrong or am i misunderstood?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Using the above equation the conduction angle is just 60, but here in
> the solution it said 120*

- The angle where conduction begins is 30° or \$\sin^{-1}(0.5)\$
- The angle where conduction stops is 150° (same formula using time symmetry)
- Therefore the diode conducts for 120°